# Laravel 5 dynamically install a package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I am relatively new to Laravel so i'm trying to seek some advice. I've read the documentation on packages provided by [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/packages). Now i understand you need a service provider to connect your package to laravel like so: `Blog\BlogServiceProvider::class`. Now what i am trying to do is have a control panel that installs packages straight off of packagist. Now i can manipulate the composer.json file quite easily in code. However, what i am trying to work around is declaring the service provider. I think it would be inconvenient if i have a dynamic installation but you have to declare the service provider yourself. Is there a way i can dynamically register the service provider in Laravel 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically add service providers through the `App` facade:

```
App::register('App\Providers\SomeServiceProvider');
```

Comment: Would this keep it in place, or would i need to have some form of initialiser that always references the installed ones? (i would keep them in my database)

Comment: I would assume it would keep it in place as this is a low level function. I don't know for sure, but I would think the providers array in the app.php file is iterated over and this is called on it. I've not tried it personally, but give it a shot.

Comment: So where would be the best place to call this function? Im going to need something to access my database then register all the providers prior to routing. How would I approach this?

Comment: To accomplish this i have created a normal service provider. Loaded my Packages model and then registered them within the register() function. Works a treat.

Comment: Great! Nice solution!